# Join two tables multiple times on same column with a lookup table in between

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

This has probably been answered but, its hard to search for this question, as you can see in my confusing title.

Anyhow, I hope this example will help:

[image: tables and desired result]

The tricky part is the one to many relationship in the parameter lookup table.

Ive tried using multiple joins and aliases resulting in a hugh number of rows since Im getting every 'amount' for every 'price'.

```
SELECT paraval.month, paraval.value as amount, paraval2.value as price, trade.position
FROM trade
INNER JOIN parameter para on trade.tID=para.tID and para.name = 'amount'
INNER JOIN parametervalues paraval on para.pID=paraval.pID

INNER JOIN parameter para2 on trade.tID=para2.tID and para2.name = 'price'
INNER JOIN parametervalues paraval2 on para2.pID=paraval2.pID
WHERE trade.type = 'cert'
```

Guessing I need sub-queries, but not sure where to place them.

EDIT add some SQL code structure :

```
CREATE TABLE #Trade  
(
    tID             int PRIMARY KEY,  
    type            varchar(50),
    position        int
 );  
CREATE TABLE #Parameter  
(
    pID             int PRIMARY KEY, 
    tID             int, 
    name            varchar(50)
);  
CREATE TABLE #ParameterValue  
(
    pID         int,  
    smonth      varchar(50),
    value       varchar(50));  


INSERT INTO #Trade 
SELECT 1, 'stock', 1
UNION
SELECT 2, 'stock', 2
UNION
SELECT 3, 'cert', 3

INSERT INTO #Parameter 
SELECT 1,1,'amount'
UNION
SELECT 2,1,'price'
UNION
SELECT 3,2,'amount'
UNION
SELECT 4,2,'price'
UNION
SELECT 5,3,'amount'
UNION
SELECT 6,3,'price'

INSERT INTO #ParameterValue
SELECT 1,1,'5'
UNION
SELECT 2,1,'500'
UNION
SELECT 3,1,'15'
UNION 
SELECT 4,1,'300'
UNION
SELECT 5,1,'5'
UNION
SELECT 5,2,'10'
UNION
SELECT 5,3,'5'
UNION
SELECT 6,1,'100'
UNION
SELECT 6,2,'200'
UNION 
SELECT 6,3,'300'

-- SELECT * FROM #Trade

-- SELECT * FROM #Parameter

-- SELECT * FROM #ParameterValue


DROP TABLE #Trade
DROP TABLE #Parameter
DROP TABLE #ParameterValue
```

Comment: Please provide your sample data and desired results as text in your initial question - it's impossible to copy/paste out of a picture.  Also, please tag your question with the version of SQL Server that you're using.  See [ask] and [mcve] for further details.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. It would be HUGELY helpful if you could your table definition as text instead of images. [Why?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Also, please explain the logic behind your desired result.  I took a long, hard look at your picture, and I can't figure out  how you're getting from Point A to Point B.

Comment: You need PIVOT operator to achieve what you want: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: You need a query that transforms rows into columns.  `amount` and `price` are values from rows in the `parameter` table, and they need to be transformed into column names.

Comment: You just need to have an additional condition for your paraval2 join as far as I can tell (`and paraval2.[month] = paraval.[month]`)

Comment: @Brian Sorry about that, I really tried to put the sample data as text but made a mess out of the formatting. I'll have a look at your links.

Comment: The desired results dont seem to match the source data, unless there are some other rules going on. for example tID 1 is referenced by pID 1 and 2, which has the values 5 and 500. How are you picking out 5 and 100?

Comment: @TomC By Filtering on trade.type = 'cert'. Only tID=3 ends up in the wanted result using 6 of the rows in the parametervalue table.

Comment: @Brian By Filtering on trade.type = 'cert'. Only tID=3 ends up in the wanted result using 6 of the rows in the parametervalue table.

Comment: @ZLK Thanks, looks very promising - I'll test this further first thing tomorrow.

Comment: @SeanLange Thank you, I will work on my formatting skills for sure. Made a complete mess out of it when I copy/pasted from notepad :P

Comment: I can see now why you pick the Cert row, but what if there is a second cert row. The answer to this is not going to be pivot, its going to be a combination of what @pascal_sanchez has suggested below, along with row_number(), with partition and order by whatever makes sense to select between multiple cert rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way for build your excepted output and relevant schema you have to use pivot with dynamic sql because in next day it possible to have some new values it’s the principal of your structure.

But i think this query can be respond :

```
SELECT paraval.month, (case when para. name = 'amount' then max(paraval.value) else null end)as amount, (case when para. name = 'price' then  max(paraval.value) else null end) as price, max(trade.position) as position 
FROM trade
INNER JOIN parameter para on trade.tID=para.tID 
INNER JOIN parametervalues paraval on para.pID=paraval.pID
WHERE trade.type = 'cert'
Group by paraval.month
```

EDIT correction off previous query :

```
CREATE TABLE #Trade  
(
    tID             int PRIMARY KEY,  
    type            varchar(50),
    position        int
 );  
CREATE TABLE #Parameter  
(
    pID             int PRIMARY KEY, 
    tID             int, 
    name            varchar(50)
);  
CREATE TABLE #ParameterValue  
(
    pID         int,  
    smonth      varchar(50),
    value       varchar(50));  


INSERT INTO #Trade 
SELECT 1, 'stock', 1
UNION
SELECT 2, 'stock', 2
UNION
SELECT 3, 'cert', 3

INSERT INTO #Parameter 
SELECT 1,1,'amount'
UNION
SELECT 2,1,'price'
UNION
SELECT 3,2,'amount'
UNION
SELECT 4,2,'price'
UNION
SELECT 5,3,'amount'
UNION
SELECT 6,3,'price'

INSERT INTO #ParameterValue
SELECT 1,1,'5'
UNION
SELECT 2,1,'500'
UNION
SELECT 3,1,'15'
UNION 
SELECT 4,1,'300'
UNION
SELECT 5,1,'5'
UNION
SELECT 5,2,'10'
UNION
SELECT 5,3,'5'
UNION
SELECT 6,1,'100'
UNION
SELECT 6,2,'200'
UNION 
SELECT 6,3,'300'


/***/
-- Perform select 
/***/
SELECT t.tID, paraval.smonth, MAX(case when para.name = 'amount' then paraval.value else null end)as amount, MAX(case when para.name = 'price' then  paraval.value else null end) as price, max(T.position) as position 
FROM #Trade T
INNER JOIN #Parameter para on T.tID=para.tID 
INNER JOIN #ParameterValue paraval on para.pID=paraval.pID
Group by T.tId, paraval.smonth
/***/

DROP TABLE #Trade
DROP TABLE #Parameter
DROP TABLE #ParameterValue
```

RESULT :

```
tID smonth  amount  price   position
1   1       5       500     1
2   1       15      300     2
3   1       5       100     3
3   2       10      200     3
3   3       5       300     3
```

Comment: Yep- this is the way to get the two columns - only question will be how to handle multiple cert rows. But this part is right.

Comment: I think group by tid , month can be work for multiple cert rows i m going to try this

Comment: @TomC hi i have update answer let me know if this query can respond